# Is it forbidden that a Muslim women do haircuts on a non Muslim or kafir woman?

Tags: fiqh, women, non-muslim, hair

I'm a woman hairdresser living in a Christian country, Am I allowed to do haircuts to woman non believers as my hairdressing business based on the Islamic laws?

Comment: Salam and welcome to IslamSE the Q&A site about Islam. To learn more about our site and our model consider taking the [tour] and checking our [help]. As to your inquiry: What makes you think it shouldn't be allowed?

Answer (score 1):

As you mentioned that your hairdressing business is based on Islamic laws than it is entirely no issue that you do hair dressing of Muslim or non Muslim women. Actually Islam being a global and final religion it does not gives laws to follow for one part of world or other, it gives us broader principles of HARAM (un Islamic) and HALAL(Islamic) to follow for whole mankind. 
In case of your business  it is not at all un islamic for hair cutting a non believer woman.